# What is the best authentication method for sails.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js

I am looking for the best approach for implementing authentication in sails.js v0.10 rc8.

Is there a formal way defined by sails.js to implement this ?

I've found module like sails-generate-auth but its documentation is not so clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a formal way defined by sails.js to implement this ?

No, nor are there any plans for one.  This is an implementation detail about which Sails is agnostic--when it comes to authentication, you have however many choices the Node community comes up with.  Which one is "best" is a matter of opinion, and off-topic for StackOverflow.  I will say that many Sails users--like many Express users--choose [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) for their authentication needs.  In a Sails v0.9 app, you can do so by adding a config file (e.g. **config/express.js** or **config/passport.js**) with the following:

```
module.exports = {
 express: {
        customMiddleware: function(app){
            app.use(passport.initialize());
            app.use(passport.session());
        }
    }
};
```

that will work in Sails v0.10 as well, although `sails.config.express` is deprecated; better to use:

```
module.exports = {
 http: {
        customMiddleware: function(app){
            app.use(passport.initialize());
            app.use(passport.session());
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can basically [follow the Passport guide](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), but use Sails actions in place of raw Express route bindings.  For example, instead of `app.post('/login')`, you'd define a Sails controller (e.g. "AuthController") with an action called "login", and route the `/login` path to that action in your `config/routes.js` file.

Comment: I tried sails-generate-auth today. Works for me! only routes.json and connections.json needs to be changed.

Comment: Custom middleware is now defined in sails.config.http [(Sail.js v.11 docs)](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Middleware#adding-or-overriding-http-middleware)